# Java JPQL: add an int value to the already existing one in Database

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql

I have a table with a column that holds int values, I need to know how to write a JPQL query that, instead of overriding the existing value, it add the new value to the existing one and persist the sum. Here is the JPQL that sets a value.

```
UPDATE Transaction t SET t.amount = :amount WHERE t.id = :id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in SQL:

```
UPDATE Transaction t SET t.amount = t.amount + 1 WHERE t.id = :id
```